# Get the second word from the div using JSoup

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, jsoup, screen-scraping

My code I gets all the words in the div. What do I need to do to only get the second word that is inside the div?

Eg:

```
<div id="div01"> FIRSTWORD SECONDWORD </DIV>
```

My code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Elements statistics = doc.select(div.div01);

textDiv1 = statistics.text();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do it like how you'd get the second word in a Java string?

```
String secondWord = line.split(" ")[1]; //add your own checks to avoid out of bounds or null exceptions.
```

Example extending what you have already:

```
if (textDiv1 != null) {
    String[] words = textDiv1.split(" ");   //split our text into individual words, which are separated by spaces
    if (words.length >= 2) {                //there are at least two words
        String secondWord = words[1];
    }
    //otherwise, there is no second word, so you can handle it here
}
//there is no text found as textDiv1 is null
```

** Unless your second word happens to be in its own element, this isn't something JSOUP would distinguish **

Comment: mmm...  
How can I apply this in my code?... sry.. im newbie

Comment: "line.split" and "words.size"  get error in android studio

Comment: @ThyagoS size is a silly mistake from me (that's for Kotlin). It should be length. split shouldn't be an error though and I tested it on my ide. Make sure you wrote your stuff beforehand and that `textDiv1` is already defined as a String

Comment: Anywhere i put line.split... does not work... the "split" get red

Comment: @ThyagoS can you post everything you have so far in your question? And what does it say when you hover over split?

Comment: @ThyagoS note that there is a space between the quotations as you are splitting the sentence into words through spaces. You should also run this once you actually retrieve the text through `text()`, not before it

Comment: i do it.. but.. the great problem.. still is the "String secondWord = line.split(" ")[1];" ... line.split got error  >> "Cannot resolve symbol 'line' "

Comment: @ThyagoS that's because you don't have the line variable. Your full text is in `textDiv1` in your example so use that. You don't need the first snippet as I gave you a full example below it

Comment: Problem Solved!! only this >> text = statistics.text().split(" ")[1]; <<   thx @AllanW =D

Answer (score 0):

@AllanW The last code was the Exemple code.. its my real code:

```
private class Div1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String text = null;
        String text2 = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                // Using Elements to get the Meta data
                Elements statistics = doc.select("div.statistics__userInfo > div");

                if (text !=null){

                    String[] words = text.split("");
                    if (words.length >= 2) {
                        String secondWord = words[1];
                    }
                }
                Elements span1 = doc.getElementsByTag("span");
                doc.getElementsByTag("span").remove();
                // Locate the content attribute
                text = statistics.text();
                text2 = span1.text();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return text;
        }
```